# Can't access attributes on a list of objects

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, hcl

My configuration code is perfect and i define module in root file but i see this error in terraform IAC

Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on ec2instance-outputs.tf line 25, in output "ec2_private_ip":
│   25:   value       = module.ec2_private.private_ip
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.ec2_private is a list of object
│
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access attribute "private_ip" for a specific element of the list, or across all elements of the list?

when i run terraform validate command i see this error but i define root module

Error: Unsupported attribute
│
│   on ec2instance-outputs.tf line 25, in output "ec2_private_ip":
│   25:   value       = module.ec2_private.private_ip
│     ├────────────────
│     │ module.ec2_private is a list of object
│
│ Can't access attributes on a list of objects. Did you mean to access attribute "private_ip" for a specific element of the list, or across all elements of the list?

Comment: Please add any relevant code to the question. Also, take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.